# proving closure for vector space

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I would like to present to my students, closure under vector addition (same situation for scalar multiplication).

I have found that this works fine:

```
Reduce[ForAll[{a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2}, Exists[{a3, b3, c3}, 
    ForAll[{x}, a1 + x*b1 + x^2*c1 + a2 + x*b2 + x^2*c2 == 
    a3 + x*b3 + x^2*c3]]],Reals]
```

producing `True`, and even:

```
Reduce[ForAll[{x}, a1 + x*b1 + x^2*c1 + a2 + x*b2 + x^2*c2 == 
    a3 + x*b3 + x^2*c3],Reals]
```

supplies a nice: `a3 == a1 + a2 && b3 == b1 + b2 && c3 == c1 + c2`

However, if I add just one more dimension, neither command finishes.

Should it be obvious to me why?

Yes, I know that this can be rewritten using the theorem for equality of coefficients of polynomials. Nonetheless I would like to use this form.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `With[{n = 10}, 
 Reduce[ForAll[{x}, 
   Table[a[i], {i, 0, n}].Table[x^i, {i, 0, n}] == 0]]]`  12.1.1 work fine both for `Reduce` or `Resolve`

Answer (score 3):

In v12.1.1.0 the following works for the extra dimension (use `Resolve` instead of `Reduce`):

```
Resolve[ForAll[{x}, 
  a1 + x*b1 + x^2*c1 + d1 x^3 + a2 + x*b2 + x^2*c2 + d2 x^3 == 
   a3 + x*b3 + x^2*c3 + x^3*d3], Reals]

(* result: c3 == c1 + c2 && d3 == d1 + d2 && b3 == b1 + b2 && a3 == a1 + a2 *)
```

You could use `SolveAlways`: for example

```
SolveAlways[
 a1 + x*b1 + x^2*c1 + a2 + x*b2 + x^2*c2 == a3 + x*b3 + x^2*c3, x
]
```

This gives `{{a1 -> -a2 + a3, b1 -> -b2 + b3, c1 -> -c2 + c3}}`.

For the next dimension up

```
SolveAlways[
 a1 + x*b1 + x^2*c1 + d1 x^3 + a2 + x*b2 + x^2*c2 + d2 x^3
  == a3 + x*b3 + x^2*c3 + x^3 *d3, x
]
```

... you have `{{a1 -> -a2 + a3, b1 -> -b2 + b3, c1 -> -c2 + c3, d1 -> -d2 + d3}}`.

You can write this somewhat more generically to avoid hand-naming all the symbols, allowing you to vary the `n` without much effort:

```
closuresolution[n_] := 
 With[{v = Array[Power[x, #] &, n, 0]}, 
  SolveAlways[Array[c1, n].v + Array[c2, n].v == Array[c3, n].v, x]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this workaround! Although I still do not understand what happens with `Reduce` going to the third degree, nor `Resolve` with the fourth degree. Nor why they have a bigger problem with the first statement I listed. Nor why `SolveAlways` is able to handle, what the others were not. Any clues would be most helpful. Thanx.